# While splitting one char array into array of char arrays, first array always displayed as random chars

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am doing a school exercise and it's asking us to split a string(character array) into multiple character arrays. A string input like this

```
"asdf qwerty zxcv"
```

should result in an array of characters arrays like this

```
"asdf","qwerty","zxcv"
```

While I am testing the code, no matter what strings I entered as the argument of my function, the first string printed out would always be some random characters, while the rest are as expected.

```
"02�9�","qwerty","zxcv"
```

Besides, my code worked fine in online compilers, which I saved [here](https://repl.it/NgHu/9). I also tested in [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/), in which the code worked pretty well too.

This is my code with the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     is_separator(char c)
{
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ' || c == '\0')
    {
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (0);
    }
}

int     ct_len(int index, char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = index;
    while (!(is_separator(str[index])))
    {
        index++;
    }
    return (index - i);
}

int     ct_wd(char *str)
{
    int     count;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (is_separator(str[i]))
            count++;
        i++;
    }
    return (count + 1);
}

char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
{
    char    **tab;
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     k;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    tab = malloc(ct_wd(str));
    while (str[j])
    {
        k = 1;
        while (is_separator(str[j]))
            j++;
        *(tab + i) = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ((ct_len(j, str) + 1)));
        while (!(is_separator(str[j])))
        {
            tab[i][k - 1] = str[j++];
            k++;
        }
        tab[i++][k - 1] = '\0';
    }
    tab[i] = 0;
    return (&tab[0]);
}

int   main(void)
{
    char** res;

    for (res = ft_split_whitespaces("asdf qwerty zxcv"); *res != 0; res++)
    {
        printf("'%s',", *res);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

One hint is that the output of the first array is changing, which suggests that there might be some problems with my memory allocation. However, I am not sure about it. If you can help me find out where the bug is, I would be really appreciative of your help. Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Well. For starters, this is wrong for several reasons: `tab = malloc(ct_wd(str));`. 1) `ct_wd` doesn't really count words, it only counts separators. 2) you want to malloc number of words * sizeof(char *)

Comment: Also, if you want to set the "last element" in your array to NULL: `tab[i] = 0;` you need to allocate size for 1 extra. However, I think the actual problem manifesting itself is somewhere else ...

Comment: @MFisherKDX Thanks! I specified the size of malloc by your suggestion and it works! But still I don't get it why you can allocate memory space to an array(as far as I understand, `(char *)` indicates a char pointer and that's it) which I don't know how much space I need and still it works?

Comment: `tab` is declared as `char    **tab;` which is an array of `char *`. So each element in the array has `sizeof(char *)`. You want to allocate space for `ct_wd(str)+1` elements, so you need to malloc `(ct_wd(str)+1)*sizeof(char *)` bytes. The extra 1 is because you are assigning a "last" array element to NULL to indicate the end of the tokens.

Comment: What exactly is the size of `(char *)`? While it is easy to tell that `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte and `sizeof(int)` would be 4 bytes, it is very confusing to me what the size of an uninitialized character array is by using `sizeof(char *)`, because while using `malloc()` to allocate memory to tab, I actually have no idea how long each of my array would be, thus making it impossible to get what the size is of each array.

Comment: It depends on your platform. `sizeof(char *)` is probably either 4 or 8. It's the number of bytes needed to represent a pointer to a char. `int *` is a pointer to int -- or an array of ints. If you need to create an array of N ints you'd `malloc(N * sizeof(int))`. Your variable `tab` is a `char **`. That's an array of `char *`. So if you needed to create an array of N elements of `char *` you'd `malloc(N * sizeof(char *))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
tab = malloc(ct_wd(str));
```

to this

```
tab = malloc(ct_wd(str) * sizeof(char *));
```

also you wight want to consider using valgrind, which should provide a fair indication of where the corruption is. essentially `ct_wd(str)` function is the main culprit along with `malloc` statement after that. you might want to take a closer look at how much memory you are allocating and how much actually using. as mentioned valgrind should assist you better.

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes <executalbe>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! It works! But still I don't get it why you can allocate memory space to an array(as far as I understand, `(char *)` indicates a char pointer and that's it) which I don't know how much space I need and still it works?

Comment: Besides, `ct_wd(str)` serves only an input of number of array of arrays I need for my `malloc()`, why it can corrupt my memory?

Comment: Pretty sure the OP needs one more element in the `tab`array to account for the last element being a `NULL` pointer. So should be `tab = malloc((ct_wd(str) + 1) * sizeof(char *))`

Comment: Actually I have the same thought. But why does this still works without allocating memory space for the `NULL` pointer?

Comment: well it never worked it just happen to be in UB state. *res != 0 <-- this statement is the key to end the list. tab = malloc(ct_wd(str)); would create a array of 3 bytes what essentially you need is an array of pointers hence tab = malloc((ct_wd(str) ) * sizeof(char *)); but then this doesn;t realy make room for the end of list viz NULL hence +1.